# How to maintain two api's within one UIViewController?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have one ViewController in that one UIImage and two UITextField's one UITableView in that i want to print the data.That data coming from api.

From  the first api i want to display the UIImage and UITextField's data.
From the Second Api load the data into UITableView. How can do that ?

Upto now i tried this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"API"];
NSString *jsonString = @"";
NSData *myJSONData =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myJSONData]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if(str.length > 0){
    NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]);
    mainBannerArray =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
}
```

Here is my Connection Delegate Methods.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
myDataQA = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[myDataQA appendData:data];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
if ((NSNull *)myDataQA != [NSNull null])
{
    if(myDataQA.length > 0)
    {
        mainBannerArray =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myDataQA options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    }
}
```

My screen like this

[image]

Comment: Why you are not using NSURLSession?

Answer (score 1):

Use AFNetworking 3.0 from Github. And call the second api in success block of first API as shown below,

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"API"]
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
// this for Image and Textfield
[manager GET:urlString parameters:nil progress:nil    success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
   // Load image and text field

   // And then call sencod url
   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager2 = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
   [manager2 GET:link2 parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
      // reload the tableview
   } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }]; 
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/when/) together with AFNetworking rather then nested API calls - the code remains clean and readable. See [Chaining promises](http://promisekit.org/chaining/) section.